# Automatic html code alteration right as page reloads/refreshes

Tags: javascript, html

How do you make it so that when you refresh a certain page, something specific in its HTML code gets changed so that you don't have too do it manually when you reload

An animation happens before displaying some information on the page, you then have to click next, but when you do, the animation resets and has to happen again but with different information, i know how to stop the animation from happening by altering the code, but i'd like to know if there's a program that could do it for me.. maybe a firefox add-on?

Comment: Do you mean [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) ?

Comment: no..
delayAnswerDisplay(1000);

this over here.. i want to change it!
change it automatically as i refresh the page.. not manually every time i click on "next" and it takes to the next part and playing the animation again

Comment: Please make a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and then post it in in here so we can help you more quickly, because I unfortunately understood nothing what you want to do...

Comment: please show what you've tried so far, code should be included in your question.

Comment: delayAnswerDisplay(1000) <--- that is in the page source code, i want to be able to change that 1000 to a 0.. but automatically when the page loads without having to inspect element and change it